# Programmatically dismiss the "swipe to delete" button/state for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app which has a `UISplitView`. The root view of the split view is a `UITableView`. When the split view is rotated portrait, the root view controller is displayed in a `UIPopoverViewController` (obviously this is standard practice).

The issue I'm having is, when iPad is in portrait rotation, if the user swipes to delete on the root view and then touches on the detail view, and then opens the root view again, the cell will still be in the same state showing the "delete" from the swipe gesture. This is not the expected behavior.

Currently I am calling `reloadData` on the table view in `viewDidDisappear` (after super) in the root view, which has the desired end result. Is there is a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could alternatively end the editing mode of the `UITableView` (probably also in `viewDidDisappear`).

```
self.tableView.editing=false;
```

Not sure if that's more efficient - more explicit perhaps.

Comment: Swear I tried that before, but it worked great. (Sorry for the delay in accepting this answer, was out of town.) Thanks :)

Comment: @Nate Pinchot, were you someplace where there is no StackOverflow? How do you get there?

Comment: You'll get a better effect if you use [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES] instead.

Comment: Note, if you do this in vewDidDisappear you may get an "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" warning. Do this in viewWillDisappear and you are all set

Comment: How can i open it programmatically (I wanna make it opens when tapping the cell not swiping it)

Comment: For me it animates whether animated is set to YES or NO, anyone else who observed the same and has a solution??

Comment: In swift 3, this has been changed to self.tableview.isEditing = false

Answer (score 6):

And to animate it:

```
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```